# Sort an array using array index

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sorting

I am stuck here......
I have two arrays Arr_title and Arr_distance 
I get sorted Arr_distance using this method

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]autorelease];

sortedFloats = [appDel.Arr_distance sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                             [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

but problem is that i want to sort Arr_title according to index of sortedFloats array...

thx in advance for help me..........

Comment: what the mean of sortedFloats arry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:Arr_title forKeys:Arr_distance];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES] autorelease];
sortedFloats = [appDel.Arr_distance sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];


NSMutableArray *sortedTitles = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *key in sortedFloats) {//or just use sortedTitles = [dict objectsForKeys:sortedFloats notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
    [sortedTitles addObject:[dict valueForKey:key]]; 
}

NSLog(@"%@",sortedValues);
```

`sortedTitles` should give you the array sorted in the same order as `sortedFloats`.

Answer (score 1):

hey instead of taking two different array take 1 dictionary with *key* `title,distance` save that dictionary in array then sort that array So you have got combination together so there is no any problem due to mapping in any sort(by title & by distance).

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question right , you can use NSDictionary for the same task

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[ @{@"title" : @"City1",@"dist" : @5},

                             @ {@"title" : @"City2",@"dist" : @2.3 },
                             @{@"title" : @"City3",@"dist" : @11.0 },
                             @{@"title" : @"City4",@"dist" : @1.0},
                             @{@"title" : @"City5",@"dist" : @.5},
                             @{@"title" : @"City6",@"dist" : @13 }]];

NSLog(@"dict<%@>",array);

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dist" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortarray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSLog(@"sort array = <%@>",sortarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution see following code.........

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]autorelease];

sortedFloats = [appDel.Arr_distance sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                             [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

 NSLog(@" Sorted Array : %@", sortedFloats);

 NSDictionary *dictTitle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:Arr_title   forKeys:appDel.Arr_distance];

// Sort the second array based on the sorted first array
sortedTitle = [dictTitle objectsForKeys:sortedFloats notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];


NSLog(@" Sorted Title : %@",sortedTitle);


// Put the two arrays into a dictionary as keys and values
NSDictionary *dictAddress = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:Arr_address   forKeys:appDel.Arr_distance];

// Sort the second array based on the sorted first array
sortedAddress = [dictAddress objectsForKeys:sortedFloats notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];


NSLog(@" Sorted Address : %@",sortedAddress);
```

Dont forgot to retain your arrays if use in another method ....